# The process will be repeated until the user enters the sentinel value, which is -1

Tags: java

i college assignement to do , I'm done all the code except one thing
they asked us (The process will be repeated until the user enters the sentinel value, which is -1)
how to do this step in java ?

Comment: Can you show us your code so far?

Comment: Please give us a little more information: what is the loop doing? Code snippet would be great.

Comment: Each customer must pay additional 10% for the Goods and Service Tax (GST). Write a
complete Java program that includes the following statements:
• Read a cashier name, a menu code and number of orders
• Calculate the GST and the total price of each customer order
• Read amount received from the customer
• Calculate the balance to be returned to the customer
• The process will be repeated until the user enters the sentinel value, which is -1

Comment: Use while loop with Scanner

Answer (score 0):

Create an overall outer **while** loop that will wrap your current method code, for example:

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

int keepLooping = 1;
while (keepLooping != -1) { // Outer loop start...
  
    /* ... All your current method code here ...
       but add a quit option to your menu, for example:  */ 
    String menuChoice = "";
    while (menuChoice.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Select menu item:");
        System.out.println(" 1) Menu Item 1");
        System.out.println(" 2) Menu Item 2");
        System.out.println(" 3) Menu Item 3");
        System.out.println(" 4) Menu Item 4");
        System.out.println(" 5) Quit");
        System.out.print("Youchoice: --> ");

        // Get input from User
        menuChoice = userInput.nextLine().trim();

        // Validate input from User. All User input should be validated!
        // Was a number from 1 to 5 (menu choice) provided?
        if (!menuChoice.matches("[1-5]")) {
            // NO...
            System.err.println("Invalid menu choice (" + menuChoice + ")! Try again...");
            System.err.println();
            menuChoice = ""; // Empty the variable so to keep looping.
        }
    } // End of Menu (inner) loop

    // A successful menu choice must have been made to get here. 
    int choice = Integer.valueOf(menuChoice);
    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            // Call a method here to carry out menu item 1 option
            break;
        case 2:
            // Call a method here to carry out menu item 2 option
            break;
        case 3:
            // Call a method here to carry out menu item 3 option
            break;
        case 4:
            // Call a method here to carry out menu item 4 option
            break;
        case 5:     // QUIT
            System.out.println(); 
            System.out.println("Quiting ... Bye-Bye"); 
            keepLooping = -1; // Sets the outer loop condition to exit it.
    } // End of switch
    System.err.println();
} // outer loop ends
```